# How to Join python graphics in BITalino?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-animation, acquisition

is there any way i can join this graphics in Python? Because BITalino sensor(data) only get a 100 samples in the graphics, so if i put 2 seconds of aquisition he wil generate something between 10 or 15 graphics, there is a way i can join this graphics and obtain something near a real-time aquisition.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zq49.png)

There is how to change da sample, but if i put 2000 for example, is not exactly a real time acquisition.

I generate the graphics, the ideia is to make a
supervisory of 2 sensors in real time or something like this.

My code look like this:

```
`SamplingRate=1000    # taxa de amostragem de 1000Hz
device.battery(0)
device.start(SamplingRate, [4])# Sensor 4(A5)


sinal_analógico = [0, 1023]
faixa_tensão = [-1.65, 1.65]   # tensão em milivolts 
variação = faixa_tensão[1] - faixa_tensão[0] # 1,65 -(-1,65) = 3,3mV



botão_start = input ("Aperte a Tecla para Inciar a Aquisição: ")
running_time = input("Escolha o tempo de aquisição: ")

start = time.time()
end = time.time()

if botão_start == "s":
    print("Aquisição Inciada \n")
    while (end - start) < int(running_time):
        # Read samples
         data = device.read(100) # Leitura do sensor
         print(data)
         plt.plot(data[:,5], 'blue', label = 'Sinal A5')  # 5 = coluna 5
         
         plt.title("Sinal ACC")
         plt.xlabel("amostras")
         plt.ylabel("bits")
         plt.show()
         end = time.time()
        
    # Script sleeps for n seconds
    time.sleep(int(running_time))
    device.stop()
    device.close()
     
  
else :
    device.stop()
    device.close()
`
```